# Statement 'RECEIVE MSG' is not supported in this version of SQL Server. for azure db

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-sql-database, signalr-hub

I am trying Database Change Notifications in my MVC Application  using SignalR and SqlDependency similar to http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

I am getting Error on Global.asax Application_Start() method "'RECEIVE MSG' is not supported in this version of SQL Server."

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString); // Error Here
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: Error details]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that [`SQLServerDependency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) requires the SQL Server Service Broker to operate.

Although Service Broker in no longer explicitly included on the [list of SQL Server features not currently supported in Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/), T-SQL commands for creating and managing Service Broker, such as [`CREATE SERVICE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190332.aspx) are marked as not supported in Azure SQL Database.

To user SignalR in Azure, you will need to set up a full instance of SQL Server running on a VM.

Comment: I cannot find Service Broker among features not currently supported in Azure SQL Database. Where exactly do they state that in the articel you reference to?

Comment: @Azimuth - that page used to include Service Broker in the list of unsupported items, but this now seems to be covered under "partially supported" - I have updated my answer with more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is because currently Service Broker is not supported in Azure SQL Database. In the article you referenced, it mentions in **DB settings section**, "**1. We need to enable the Service Broker on our database(TechBrijDB).**". So you'll need to enable Service Broken first on your database to make the code work. You can vote this feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/423275-enable-sql-service-broker-in-sql-azure).

Alternatively, you could use an [Azure SQL VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-server-provision/) instead. You can find the difference between them in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-paas-vs-sql-server-iaas/).

Hope this helps.